# Objects field in callback function PHP

Tags: php, oop, callback

I'm creating a class to manage user submitted articles. Within this class, I'm also using the [PHP Simple Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class. This class allows you to apply a callback function when it outputs HTML, which I use to filter out unwanted elements. Outside of a class, in procedural style, it's implemented by doing this:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html($_FILES["repfile"]["tmp_name"]);

function fileFilter($element){
    $toDelete = array("img", "script", "object", "iframe");
    foreach($toDelete as $el){
        if($element->tag==$el){
              $element->outertext = "";
        }
    }
}
$html->set_callback("fileFilter");
$finalContent = (string)$html->find("div", 0)->innertext;
?>
```

Now what I want to do in my class is something along the lines of

```
<?php
class Article{
public $blockedElements;
public $html;

function __toString(){
    $html->set_callback("Article::htmlFilter");
    return (string)$html;
}

public static function htmlFilter($element){
    foreach($this->blockedElements as $el){
        if($element->tag==$el){
            $element->outertext = "";
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

The obvious problem is that you can't use the `$this->blockedElements` in a static method, so how would I be able to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not making `htmlFilter` static.

Assuming you got an Article *instance*, you can pass the instance as a callback as well:

```
function __toString(){
    $html->set_callback(array($this, "htmlFilter"));
    return (string)$html;
}
```

If you do that, then `htmlFilter` will also be called as an instance method (provided you remove the `static` keyword).

Comment: Oh christ, is it really that simple? For some reason I was thinking that it wouldn't be in the scope for a call back!

Comment: Yep, I've tested it and you're right! Cheers for making the edit afterwards, I would never have thought to pass an array into the callback

Comment: Yeah, a *callable* can have a couple of forms. One of them is an array with instance and method name. For a more complete description, see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php